# How do I set character encoding to UTF-8 for default.html?

Tags: html, character-encoding

I spent the last few hours getting my website to validate *HTML 4.01 Strict* and I actually have succeeded in that, but there is still one warning which I can't get rid of. The warning is:

> Character Encoding mismatch!
>
> The character encoding specified in
> the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) is
> different from the value in the 
> element (utf-8). I will use the value
> from the HTTP header (iso-8859-1) for
> this validation.

The page in question is [www.dubiousarray.net/default.html](http://www.dubiousarray.net/default.html). As you can see from the page source I have the following meta element:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
```

and I have made sure that the default.html file is saved with UTF-8 encoding. The strange thing is all the other pages in the site validate without this warning and they have the same meta tag and were saved in exactly the same way. I am pretty sure it is something to do with the server configuration. The .htaccess file looks like this at the moment:

```
# Use PHP 5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

But I have tried all the fixes shown on [this page](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/setting-charset-in-htaccess.html) and none of them worked. How can I go about getting rid of this warning?

In Firefox, if you right click on the page and select 'View Page Info', *default.html* shows as ISO-8859-1, while all the other pages show UTF-8.

All the html file have been created and saved in the exact same way (character encoding set to UTF-8 without [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)), but *default.html* is the only one which isn't displaying as UTF-8. So I assume the server is doing something special to the *default.html* file though I am not sure what as there is not sign of it in the *.htaccess* file.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to replace the HTTP-level header.

This should work:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?>
```

Note that the above must be the first thing in your file. No exceptions. See *[header](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)*.

For general information on how to change the character set header in different web stacks, see *[Setting the HTTP charset parameter](http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset)*.

Comment: That looks like it should fix the problem as it comes after the server messes with it but as I no longer have the default.html file that was causing the problem I can't test it. I'm going to assume it would have worked though :-).

Comment: But this doesn't work for a static HTML page (even if the question mentions some unrelated PHP setting in a configuration file).

Answer (score 2):

The server is clearly marking the document as ISO-8859-1 in the HTTP headers. Try saving default.html using UTF-8 encoding with a proper editor.

Comment: The default.html file has been saved as UTF-8 with a proper editor (UTF-8 without BOM to be exact). And I am almost certain that the encoding is correct when I save it as all the other pages on the site are shown as UTF-8 when inspected by Firefox. The server seems to be doing something special to the default.html file.

Answer (score 2):

Include this in your code:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Re *"in your code"*: Don't you mean in the static HTML file?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I have come up with a partial solution to my problem. As it was only the *default.html* file which was causing the warning I assumed that the server was doing something special to it because of its name. So I made a new file called *home.html* with the same contents as the *default.html* file and pointed the *.htaccess* file to the new file (see line 3 below).

```
# Use PHP5 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php5 .php
DirectoryIndex home.html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

This fixed the problem and all files are now recognised as UTF-8. I'm still not sure what the server was doing to the *default.html* file or where the settings concerning that are, but as my problem is gone I will forget about that.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `AddDefaultCharset` from `.htaccess` and check the encoding.

I saved the HTML source of your webpage and opened it. Encoding was detected as UTF-8. However, on viewing the same webpage served by your web server, the encoding is ISO-8859-1. That is why I suggest removal of the former redundant rule.

Comment: I removed that rule from the .htaccess file as you are right, it does seem redundant, it didn't do anything to fix the problem though.