# Special characters of SQL display as ? in HTML

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax

In my tabel I have this special character for example "č"

When I select and display this data as html on my website it shows that character as a question mark (?).

How could I solve this?

Example Table

```
Mehanički
```

Example HTML output

```
Mehani?ki
```

Im using PHP to get the data from SQL and I call the PHP file with AJAX to get the output which is an array

Comment: You should look into character encoding -- this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905173/how-do-i-set-character-encoding-to-utf-8-for-default-html

Comment: I am using <meta charset="ISO-8859-2"> but it doesn't change a thing about that. It works on the whole website but not in the data that I get.

Answer (score 1):

put `<meta charset="utf-8">` in your head block.

Also, the collation of your database should be utf8_unicode_ci.

ALSO, your source-code should be encoded in utf8 too.

Comment: I have even set the collation of the field itself to the right one "latin2_croatian_ci" but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to set your html encoding to that one you use in the database.

Comment: What encoding do you recommend?

Comment: Probably should have been a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had to put this after connecting to my database

```
if (!$mysqli->set_charset("latin2")) {
    printf("Error loading character set latin2 : %s\n", $mysqli->error);
}
```